# use sequelize (javascript ORM) to edit, load data table without drop them (mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

In a node app, I am using express and [sequelize ORM](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/)

But I notice when I edit a model class, my updates are not in my database.

For example, this the article model named `article.js` :

```
'use strict';

const SequelizeSlugify = require('sequelize-slugify');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let Article = sequelize.define('Article', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    url: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    slug: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        // Article.hasMany(models.Comments);
      }
    }
  });

  SequelizeSlugify.slugifyModel(Article, {
        source: ['title'],
        overwrite: false
    });

  return Article;
};
```

If I add a field like this in this model :

```
testField: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  unique: true,
  allowNull: false
}
```

Even if I restart the server with the cmd `npm start`, none of my edits are loaded or registered in the database.
Indeed, in order to update my data tables I have to drop them and restart my node server.

Moreover, I would like to know why Sequelize register my model, for example here `article.js` as plural name like Articles in  my database. How to prevent from this behavior ?

The file `article.js` is in my folder `models`, to import models into database I have in the same folder the `index.js` file like this:

```
'use strict';

const fs        = require('fs');
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config    = require(__dirname+'/database.json');
const db        = {};

let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.dbname, config.db.user, config.db.password, {
  host: config.db.host,
  port: config.db.port
});

fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').filter(function (file) {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0);
}).forEach(function (file) {
  let model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname + '/models', file));
  db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the plural table name. In fact I have to include the model definition in the Sequelize declaration.

Following the doc [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#definition), I add some argument when I declare **new Sequelize** in `database.js` like this:

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.dbname, config.db.user, config.db.password, {
    host: config.db.host,
    port: config.db.port,
    define: {
        // And deletedAt to be called destroyTime (remember to enable paranoid for this to work)
        deletedAt: 'destroyTime',
        paranoid: true,
        // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
        underscored: true,
        // disable the modification of table names; By default, sequelize will automatically
        // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
        freezeTableName: true
    }
});
```

The rest of the file is still the same as I wrote in my initial post.

Thank you and happy coding. I hope this could help some of you !

**If someone know more about how to update data table without drop them directly from mysql, don't hesitate to edit his answer.**